# Wrong if statement condition

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have 2 recyclerview. I want to add different types of book images to different lines in the horizontal plane. But when I add a book, it is added to both of recyclerview. Where's my mistake?

**for loop:**

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) ds.getValue();

                        mBaslik.add(hashMap.get("baslik"));
                        mFotoUrl.add(hashMap.get("downloadurl"));

                        if(hashMap.get("baslik").equals("Roman")){
                            initRecyclerView();
                        }
                        else if(hashMap.get("baslik").equals("Hikaye")){
                            initRecyclerView2();

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: hashMap.get("baslik") is null

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/8035209

Comment: Try this if(hashMap.get("baslik") != null  && hashMap.get("baslik").equals("Roman"))

Comment: No Anas. Start with the string literal when comparing with equals. `"Roman".equals(hashMap.get("baslik"))`, that way you avoid the NPE and the extra != null check.

Answer (score 1):

hashMap.get("baslik") result is null, The equals method belongs to java.lang.String

you can:

```
"Roman".equals(hashMap.get("baslik"))
```

Comment: It doesn't work exactly right. When I added two books, it added the novel to the first recyclerview. Secondly I added the story, this time added two books to two recyclerview.

Comment: @Old Schooled , How can we fix this issue?

Comment: This is just a solution to your "java.lang.NullPointerException" problem.

Comment: How can I edit this question to it does not dublicate question?